# Ionic show data which is equal to the value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Im using ngFor for sliding items. But i need to show that items only which have event value upcoming.

I need to only show that array which have the event value active. Thanks

```
<ion-slide class="slide" *ngFor="let y of upcoming" (click)='details(y)'>
  <ion-card class="box" style="background-color: white">
    <img  [src]="y.picture1" class="image"/>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="column1" style="background-color: white">
              <h3> {{y.days}} Days</h3>
          </div>

           <div class="column2" style="background-color: white">
              <div class="tourdescription">{{y.title}}</div>
              <div class="tourdate">{{y.date}}</div>
           </div>    
       </div>
  </ion-card>
</ion-slide>
```

.ts

```
  getUpcoming(){
    this.authService.getUpcoming().pipe(
    map(actions => actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data();
    const id = a.payload.doc.id;

     return { id, ...data };
     }))
   ).subscribe(resp=>{
   console.log(resp);
   this.upcoming = resp; 
   });
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
  getUpcoming(){
    this.authService.getUpcoming().pipe(
    map(actions => actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data();
    const id = a.payload.doc.id;

     return { id, ...data };
     }))
   ).subscribe(resp=>{
       console.log(resp);
       this.upcoming = resp.filter(item => item.event === 'upcoming'); 
   });
  }
```

with RXJS Operation

```
  import { filter } from 'rxjs/operations'

  getUpcoming(){
    this.authService.getUpcoming().pipe(
    map(actions => actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data();
    const id = a.payload.doc.id;

     return { id, ...data };
     }))
   ).pipe(
      filter(item.event === 'upcoming') 
   )
    .subscribe(resp=>{
       console.log(resp);
       this.upcoming = resp; 
   });
  }
```

Comment: very nice one but will be more cleaner if we use rxjs filter operator 

Answer (score 3):

What I see here is that you are getting all the data in the value `this.upcoming`

So what you have to do is simply add something like this :

```html
<ion-card class="box" style="background-color: white" *ngIf="y.event == 'upcoming'">
  YOUR CODE
</ion-card>
```

Comment: Or there is also the codal solution of @Hamza Neffati, but if your are going to use the "past" value after that, mine is the front-end way to do that

Comment: you are correct  , but this will add `ion-slide` compoenent for every item without the `ion-card` that why we need to use ng-container  , check my asnwer

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you write a pipe to filter the events which are upcoming.May be there will be a use case, where you need to manipluate the entire events. So to play on safer side , you can filter using pipes , instead to using ngIf or filtering in component.

events.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'events'
})
export class EventsPipe implements PipeTransform {



  transform(events: Array<any>,type:string): Array<any> {
    if(!type)
      return events;
    return events.filter(event=>event['event'] == type);
  }

}
```

your-component.html

```
<!-- Upcoming -->
<ion-slide class="slide" *ngFor="let y of upcoming | events:'upcoming'" (click)='details(y)'>

<!-- Past -->
<ion-slide class="slide" *ngFor="let y of upcoming | events:'past'" (click)='details(y)'>
```

Comment: good job of using pipe , this consider the best answer for me it is very clean in term of typescript and the template  

Answer (score 0):

try to use `ng-conatiner` and `ngIf` , this will prevent adding `ion-slide` compoenet in case of the event is upcomming

```
<ng-conainer *ngFor="let y of upcoming" >
<ion-slide class="slide" (click)='details(y)' *ngIf="y.event == 'upcoming'">  
  <ion-card class="box" style="background-color: white">
   ....
  </ion-card>
</ion-slide>
</ng-container>
```